# Accessing non-active account on metamask

Tags: transactions, metamask

I want to transfer ownership of an already notarized file with a particular address.  I am using smart contract and representing ownership by "msg.sender" i.e. selected account in metamask is the owner.

Problem is that I am trying to call smart contract function using a address from the metamask account list that is not currently active but I  am only able to fetch the currently selected one in metamask.

Is there any way to access the account not currently selected in metamask and making transaction using it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you are asking. You can't send a transaction from an account which you don't own. So what would you like to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Are you using a smart contract? How is ownership represented in that contract?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen i am working with test network and i have added multiple accounts in my metamask, for testing purpose i want to transfer ownership of a notarized file from one account to another.

Comment: @Ismael yes, i am using smart contract and i am representing ownership by "msg.sender". means selected account in metamask is the owner. account[0]

Answer (score 0):

An approach can be to have a mapping from document's hash to owner address.

```
mapping (bytes32 => address) ownership;
```

Now to transfer ownership you have to override the old owner with the new one

```
event NewOwner(bytes32 docId, address newOwner);

function transferOwnership(bytes32 docId, address newOwner) public {
    // Only the owner can transfer ownership
    require(ownership[docId] == msg.sender);
    ownership[docId] = newOwner;
    emit NewOwner(docId, newOwner);
}
```